# Dropdown Monthly archive of particular category

Tags: wordpress, categories

In wordpress I want to have the dropdown for monthly archive of particular category.

```
<select name="archive-menu"   onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">Select month</option>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=option'); ?>
</select>
```

The above code shows all categories. Is there a way to do with modified code or suitable plugin available for this purpose to filter for particular category only ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/single-category-archives-1) discusses this, they say you could either use `wp_list_categories()` or the [WordPress plugin Archives for a category](http://kwebble.com/projects/wp-plugin-afac)

Comment: I had already tried the above plugins but it is not updated / maintained for long time. It is not working for drop down. I don't want as widget also.